# How to identify features from WMS in QField?

Tags: wms, qfield, getfeatureinfo, identify

Does the function "Identify Features", from QGIS Desktop, to query data from a WMS service exist in QField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the OPENGIS.ch GitHub issues for QField, this is not currently possible.

Reference: [Feature suggestion: Identify WMS layers](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/517)